# Nginx rewrite sub domain to parameter value

Tags: nginx, rewrite

How can I rewrite: `http://anything.example.com` to `http://example.com/?p=anything`? In real use, `anything` will be a project name and varies.

I have tried this in my config,

```
if ($host ~* (.*)\.example\.com) {
    set $sub_domain $1;
    rewrite ^/$ /?p=$sub_domain;
}
```

I have also set up the sub domain in my hosts file:

`127.0.0.1  proj_a.example.com`

But going to http://proj_a.example.com shows a page served by another config file.

Comment: I suggest you read [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names).

Comment: What do you mean by "another config file"?

Comment: @RichardSmith I have several config files in /etc/nginx/sites-available which are sym-linked to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled. One of these has /var/www as its root which is served in this case.